# Python Regex DUPLICATE_NAMES Flag

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

Many regex sites mention the `(?J)` flag to allow duplicate names.

Does this exist in Python or is there any way to allow duplicate names within a regex? It is not listed in the Python docs, but is it possible to enable it by passing a certain int flag? Is it possible to manually add this support?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the regex module re doesn't allow duplicate named subpatterns at all. The `(?J)` feature exists only in PCRE.

However [the new regex module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex) allows you to use duplicate named captures by default.

Comment: Is the new `regex` module going to be added to the standard library or is it slated to seamlessly replace `re` at some version in the future?

Comment: @natdempk: I think that this module will replace the re module in the futur, however I am not Nostradamus.

Comment: Thanks, this answered my question. Good to know it will be hopefully coming in the future.